# Java Are Calls to an Atomic Method Atomic

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, atomic

I couldn't really think of a great title for this question, but the question is would the following call to `Atomic.set` in the `Foo` constructor be atomic, or could the thread switch before the call to `AtomicInteger.set`?

```
public class Foo {
  private final Atomic atomic = new Atomic();

  public Foo() {
    atomic.set(10);
  }

  private static class Atomic {
    private final AtomicInteger atomicInt = new AtomicInteger();

    public void set(int i) {
      atomicInt.set(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What would go wrong if the thread switched before the call to `AtomicInteger.set`?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I didn't actually get that far; was just curious...

Comment: Atomicity is not about preventing context switches. It's about making sure that any thread always sees a consistent, correct state, despite context switches.

Comment: I think you may misunderstand what atomic means. It doesn't mean that nothing can happen before or after the call -- it's that nothing can go "in the middle of" the call. For instance, if you do `i.set(0)` in one thread and `i.set(-1)` in another thread, you won't see some bits with 0 and others with 1 -- that is, it won't ever look like one thread wrote the 0s in the middle of another thread writing the 1s.

Comment: @JBNizet + yshavit, I understand what atomic means, I'm just curious as to what happens here, i.e. if a method is called, and that method is one atomic operation, will the whole method call be atomic?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by that? I think you really need to answer Louis Wasserman's question.

Comment: @JBNizet I'll try to clarify in the question.

Comment: I don't think it's a significant distinction. If a method body *only* does one atomic operation, then even if it's possible that there's a context switch inside the method body before or after entering the atomic operation, nothing useful has occurred. So it is "effectively" atomic.

Comment: I think that what's confusing here is that storing a value into an `int` variable is _always_ atomic.  The meaning of "atomic" might be easier to explain if we were talking about `atomicInteger.CompareAndSet(e,n)` instead of just `.set(n)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no guarantee in the Java Language Specification or Java Virtual Machine Specification that there is no other Thread running between the invocation of the method itself and the invocation of `atomic.set()` inside it.

It all depends on the JVM, your hardware, etc. If you have multiple CPU's, the other CPU's won't even know where one CPU is in the code, unless you use Thread synchronization features in Java. (which you are not doing, at least not between the beginning of your method add the invocation of `atomic.set`)

The leaves the question "why do you care?" but the above is the answer to the question that you asked.

Comment: As to why I care, "curiosity killed the cat, but satisfaction brought it back"

Comment: A more interesting question than "why do you care?" is "how would you know?" Atomicity is about observable results: what will you see, what won't you say, what might you maybe see? If two scenarios have the same answers to those questions, then from the perspective of atomicity they're the same scenario. The _performance_ characteristics might possibly be different, but that's a different question.